# Trying to import a img in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, import, importerror

I am trying to import an image at the top of my file because my first time trying to return the code below did not work.

[Image doesn't show using this code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2ebp.png)

```
                        <img src={require('../../blogPostImages/' + post.blogImage)} 
    alt="Post Image"/>
```

I am importing this code at the top of the file as

```
    import Img from '../../blogPostImages/' + post.blogImage;
```

and returning in a div as:

[page doesn't load with this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHL8O.png)

I get a Failed to Compile error, I believe it has to do with the plus sign.

Comment: and returning in a div as: <img src={Img} alt="Post Image"/>

Comment: just  <img src={'../../blogPostImages/' + post.blogImage'}  />

Comment: @robert the page loads now but I still get the broken image icon as in it doesn't load the image

Comment: cause your path is not valid. (check what lock image src path in browser)   "./" will refer to your public folder. so probably you don't need "../../" on beginning

Answer (score 1):

In the `src` attribute of the `img` element you should specify directly the route to the file, as in plain HTML.

With string interpolation:

```
<img src={`../../blogPostImages/${post.blogImage}`} 
    alt="Post Image"/>
```